# will the data of coredata be deleted after updating ios app from app store?

Tags: ios, core-data

my app uses Coredata to help user manage pictures and videos and i will for sure update this app from appstore after some time, for the update the coredata model will not be changed. So after updating this app will pictures and videos which are already saved in the original coredata model still appear in the updated app? Thank you all!

Comment: Try it. Install the App Store version of your app onto a device. Add some data through the app. Now install the new version of your app through Xcode. Is the data still there?

Comment: hi, rmaddy. My App is not in App store yet. Can i do this test with Testflight? Just upload two App Versions to Testflight and then test with my device?

Comment: If your app isn't in the store then no user will be performing an upgrade so there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: No, your data will not be deleted, Yes it will persist.

You said the model is not changing, which would/could cause problems, but otherwise data wont be affected by an app store update.

Comment: Oops. my answer of Yes was thinking in terms of "Will the data still be there" and `YES` it will still be there, `NO` it won't be deleted. sheesh, no need to downvote, It's a correct answer lol

Comment: Update your answer to avoid confusion

Comment: Don't know who downvoted you but the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> will the data of coredata be deleted after updating ios app from app store?

Of course `NO`.
Your data persists on your device already.
And moreover - even if you will update your data model - data will persist too.   But in that case, you will get a crash.
To prevent an app from the crash you should implement migration from the previous data model to the current one.

Check this out for more info [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)